# How execute methods at same in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have **two function** and I need to **execute it at same** time using javacript or any parallel function.
How can i do?

Thank so.

Comment: which implementation of javascript (browser? node?), and why

Comment: you start by thinking and doing the problem before asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Look at this question it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/7683064/1815624

Comment: Look i have two function. And what i need is: 
Hown I execute it at same time

Comment: way to not answer any of the questions!

Comment: @RafaelMillares you have a conceptual problem if u need two functions running at the same time + javascript is not multithreaded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find exactly what you're looking for. Does it have to be exactly at the same time? Javascript is single-threaded. But you could do async calls. Would that meet your use case? If not, you could check out Web Workers, but I've never used that before.

[Can javascript run multiple functions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465787/can-javascript-run-multiple-functions-at-once)

[Simultaneous code in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004463/simultaneous-code-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank so much. It's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Awesome :) best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is fundamentally not multithreaded. It just processes events in a single pipeline.

There is an npm package that can do multithreading if that's what you really need here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads